# Java Sorted concurrent collection

Tags: java, sorting, concurrency

Is anyone aware about any concurrent collection in Java which provides sorted behavior ? and if it is how does it work internally?

Comment: `ConcurrentSkipListSet<E>`

Comment: Maybe interresting for you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398338/concurrent-sorting-in-java

Comment: did you try googling it?? "concurrent collections in java"... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Answer (score 4):

`ConcurrentSkipListSet` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap` is what you are looking for, which are equivalent of `TreeSet` and `TreeMap`